# Reconstructing a quad tree from a depth-first traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, quadtree

I've been working on a decoder that reconstructs data encoded as a depth-first traversal of a quad tree structure. When I encode the offset of each, its pretty simple.

```
deconstructed_matrix = np.empty([int(256), int(256)])
elem, row = 0, 0
while row < n:
    while elem < n:
         deconstructed_matrix[row + yOff][elem + xOff] = val
         elem += 1
    row += 1
    elem = 0
```

I know that there must be some way to get the x and y offset from the depth-first search of the quad tree, but I am totally puzzled on how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide examples of input and expected output. Also tag with the programming language (`python`) and `numpy` if you want to attract the right audience.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Trincot. And Jackie you would find it easy if you draw something and post here. Solving manually on paper before coding works for me.

Comment: @trincot Right now Im just thinking about how to develop an algorithm that would do this. I'll try to draw something out and work on it some more myself